# Is it possible to get infected with HIV from old blood?

Tags: hiv, infection

Let's say that someone uses a needle which has some old blood infected with HIV. In this case, is it possible for them to get infected with HIV?

Comment: Doesn't the oxygen of air eliminate the virus?

Comment: It's important to define how old is "old", here, I think.  I rephrased the question a bit so that it focuses more on the science than an individual diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks. Let's not define old in order to have a complete answer. I suppose the answer is based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can transmit HIV with infected needles/syringes. This is a quite common mechanism of transmission when drug addicts share and re-use needles and syringes and also in third world hospitals with poor hygiene standards.

A drop of blood is considered infectious at least until it has completely dried up (some research showed that it might be contagious for up to 5 days longer when the conditions are right, see reference 1 below). Mostly HIV is senstive against high temperatures (over 60°C), while it is stable at low temperatures. It is very sensitive against shifts in pH (below 7 or above 8) and also against desinfectants like bleach. Have a look at the references below, a lot of research has been done by Abdala et al. in this field. You can find his whole reference list [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Abdala%20N%5BAuthor%5D&cauthor=true&cauthor_uid=10921429) (it contains more articles in this field).

---

References:

1. [Survival of HIV-1 activity after disinfection, temperature and pH
   changes, or drying.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1802953)
2. [Survival of HIV-1 in syringes.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9928733)
3. [Survival of HIV-1 in syringes: effects of temperature during
   storage.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10921429)
4. [Viability of HIV-1 in syringes: implications for interventions among
   injection drug users.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10932845)